# textmate 2.0 alpha.9543 not automatic use ruby document type

Tags: textmate2

Yesterday I upgraded alpha.9543, When I open a ruby file does not automatically switch ruby document type.

I have already installed Ruby bundle. But other bundle is work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate
```